# How to change format Date react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to change the format date in DD/MM/YYYY , HH:MM if anyone have a idea please ? My code :

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sport: {
        clubs: [],
      },
      rival: {
        clubs: [],
      },
      dateMatch: '',
      DB: {sound: []},
    };
  }
```

call here

```
          <Text
            style={{
              textAlign: 'center',
              marginTop: 30,
              fontSize: 18,
              backgroundColor: 'rgba (209,209,209, .4)',
            }}>
            le {element.dateMatch}
          </Text>
```

Thanks for watching !

Comment: Have a look at moment.js: https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do with **[momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)** package

To install moment on your project run this command

```
npm install moment --save
```

Then you can import it in your code

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

For date convert, use below example console log

```
console.log( moment('2018-01-01 13:40:39').format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm a') );
```

Just pass your date value inside moment

Comment: Perfect it works, do you have an idea to have the time format in French ?